# Finding Net salary from the Gross saraly and saraly tax

Tags: java, eclipse

Right now I am stuck on this task:

The method should take the gross salary, calculate the tax amount, subtract it and return the net salary.

The tax rate will be applied by the following rules:

```
salary >= 45,000 pays a 50% tax rate, 
       >= 30,000 pays a 30% and 
          everyone else pays 15%.
```

Here is my code:

```
public double salaryTax(double salary) {

    double taxRate=0;

    if (salary >= 45.000) {
         taxRate = .5;

    }
    else if (salary >= 30.000) {
        taxRate = .3;
    }
    else
    {
        taxRate = .15;
    }
    double tax = salary * taxRate;
    double totalTax = tax + taxRate;
    double netSalary = salary - totalTax;
    return  netSalary;
}
```

However, when ever I test it, it is 0.5 away from the actual amount I am supposed to have...

Comment: 45,000 is `45000`, `45.000` is 45.

Comment: why do you add the `taxRate` to the tax?

Comment: I got it!!  Thank you! Don´t even know why I have done that lol...

Comment: you could have initialized taxrate to .15 and saved some lines of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope it will help

```
public double salaryTax(double salary) {

    double taxRate = 0.15;

    if (salary >= 45000) {
         taxRate = 0.5;

    }
    else if (salary >= 30000) {
        taxRate = 0.3;
    }

    return  salary*(1.0- taxRate);
}
```